# Executing multiple JavaScript functions one after the other if event.keyCode==13

Tags: javascript, php, function

I'm trying to execute 2 JavaScript functions one after the other when event.keyCode == 13. The problem is that while it works with one function, it stops working if there are two or more functions. Please take a look at my code:

```
<?php

echo "

<input type = "text"
onKeyDown=\"
if(event.keyCode==13) 
ajaxPass('one','two');
ajaxPass('three','four');
\">

";

?>
```

Comment: 1) You need to wrap multiple statements in `{ }` to be covered by the same `if`.   2) `ajaxPass` sounds like it runs asynchronously, so you need to serialize them via callbacks if you need to run sequentially 3) if `onKeyDown` gets longer than a single function call, better make it a separate function and just call that

Comment: This really doesn't seem to be about php, it would be better to make it a pure javascript question.

Comment: What does "stops working" mean? Does the code fail entirely? Are any errors thrown? Are no functions executed? Are the second and subsequent lines always executed even if the keyCode isn't 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callback functionality to accomplish that approach

```
function a(callback) {
// at the end of this function
callback();
}

function b() {}

// then call them like this
a(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
<input type = "text"
  onKeyDown="
    if(event.keyCode==13) {
      ajaxPass('one','two');
      ajaxPass('three','four');
    }
">
```

The condition 'if' will execute only the first line, if '{}' are missing.

Comment: What you mean is that without the brackets, only the first statement after the *if* is conditional, the second will always execute. Perhaps this isn't the issue: "*…it stops working if there are two or more functions*", since "stops working" isn't defined.